# How to convert child JSON structure to C# object graph

Tags: c#, json, json.net, sql-server-2016, json-deserialization

I'm using SQL Server 2016's FOR JSON to convert a SQL Server SELECT statement into a JSON string.  My intention is to have C# convert produced JSON string into an object.

**SQL Server Server select statement:**

```
SELECT
    Id AS PersonId, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Name, 
    Birthday,
    (
        SELECT
            PhoneNumber.PhoneNumberTypeId, 
            PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber             
        FROM            
            PhoneNumber 
            INNER JOIN PhoneNumberType ON PhoneNumber.PhoneNumberTypeId = PhoneNumberType.Id
        WHERE
            PhoneNumber.PersonId = Person.Id
        FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES       
    ) AS PhoneNumberList
FROM            
    Person
ORDER BY
    LastName
FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

**C# Object I'm trying to convert the data to:**

```
public class PersonDataContract : IPersonDataContract
{
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; }
    public IList<IPhoneNumberDataContract> PhoneNumberList { get; set; }

    public PersonDataContract()
    {
        PhoneNumberList = new List<IPhoneNumberDataContract>();
    }
}
```

**Raw JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "PersonId": 5,
        "FirstName": "Squire",
        "LastName": "Escrow",
        "Name": "Squire Escrow",
        "Birthday": "2001-12-12",
        "PhoneNumberList": "[{\"PhoneNumberTypeId\":1,\"PhoneNumber\":\"8129091423\"}]"
    }, 
    {
        "PersonId": 6,
        "FirstName": "Vilhelm",
        "LastName": "Huldsputh",
        "Name": "Vilhelm Huldsputh",
        "Birthday": "1953-11-13",
        "PhoneNumberList": "[{\"PhoneNumberTypeId\":1,\"PhoneNumber\":\"9871237171\"},{\"PhoneNumberTypeId\":2,\"PhoneNumber\":\"8189991212\"}]"
    }
]
```

**Code converting raw JSON to Object:**

```
...
using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var jsonString = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonDataContract>>(jsonString);
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

This process works as long as I remove PhoneNumberList from the raw JSON.  I think the problem is I'm using 2 'FOR JSON PATH's in my SQL Statement (one for the PhoneNumberList itself and one for the overall SELECT Statement) which is causing the PhoneNumberList to be converted into a String which is not getting converted into an array.

How do you convert the child string representing a collection of phone numbers into an array of IPhoneNumberDataContract?

Comment: `...Birthday, JSON_QUERY(SELECT ...)`.

Comment: Make PhoneNumberList of PersonDataContract as string and then deserialize each of this string to PhoneNumberDataContract.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - your suggestion solved the issue.  Can you answer the question please so I can accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *sort of* covered in [the FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server):

> **Question**. I have JSON text stored in a table column. I want to include it in the output of `FOR JSON`. But `FOR JSON` escapes all
>   characters in the JSON, so I'm getting a JSON string instead of a
>   nested object [..]
>
> **Answer.** JSON stored in a text column or a literal is treated like any text. That is, it's surrounded with double quotes and escaped. If
>   you want to return an unescaped JSON object, pass the JSON column as
>   an argument to the `JSON_QUERY` function [..]

It doesn't mention explicitly that any non-trivial subquery that uses `FOR JSON` will also produce an escaped value, and requires `JSON_QUERY` in this way. So use

```
SELECT
    Id AS PersonId, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Name, 
    Birthday,
    JSON_QUERY(
        SELECT
            ...
        FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES       
    ) AS PhoneNumberList
```

By "non-trivial", I mean that a query like this does *not* require `JSON_QUERY`:

```
SELECT 
    'Foo' AS Foo, (
        SELECT 1 AS A 
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) AS Bar
FOR JSON PATH
```

`Bar` will not be escaped here, since the optimizer apparently remembers it's dealing with JSON. I haven't yet been able to find a consistent set of rules that governs this ([different question, same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45942184/4137916)), and it's not even clear if this is intended behavior or a bug, but `JSON_QUERY` will bail you out regardless. It should probably always be used, to prevent surprises with a query going from "simple" to "complex" and suddenly needing it.